# Python: Replace characters in a string by position

Tags: python

Trying to replace characters in a string only by position.

Here is what I have, any help would be appreciated!

```
for i in pos:
    string=string.replace(string[i],r.choice(data))
```

Comment: Why not keep it as a list instead of as a string? Then you could just do `newhand[i] = r.choice(cardset)`

Comment: strings are immutable. Create a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just replace it directly?

```
for i in pos:
    newhand=newhand.replace(newhand[i],r.choice(cardset))
```

goes to:

```
for i in pos:
    newhand[i]=r.choice(cardset)
```

This is assuming that `hand` is a list and not a string.
If `hand` is a string at this point in the program,
I would recommend keeping it as a list, as strings are not able to be changed because they are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)

If you want to keep hand as a string, you could always do:

```
newhand = ''.join([(x,r.choice(cardset))[i in pos] for i,x in enumerate(newhand)])
```

But this will convert `newhand` to a list and then join it into a string before storing it back into `newhand`.

Also, The line:

```
if isinstance(pos, int):
                pos=(pos,)
```

should be changed to:

```
pos = [int(index) for index in pos.split(',')]
```

You don't need `isinstance` because that will always return false.

Comment: I get this error with that solution:
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @user2218235 use the second solution if you want to keep `hand` as a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue with string yet, this is the solution:

```
newhand = '{0}{1}{2}'.format(newhand[:i], r.choice(cardset), newhand[i + 1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the replace function.  When you call the replace function it replaces *ALL* instances of the first argument with the second argument.

so, if newhand = AKAK9, newhand.replace("A","Q") will result in newhand = QKQK9.

If possible, change the string to a list, then do the following to change the specific index:

```
for i in pos:
    newhand[i]=r.choice(cardset)
```

If needed, you can then change the newhand list back to a string by using str():

```
hand = ''.join(str(e) for e in newhand_list)
```

Comment: Only if `hand` is a `list`, which it is not in his program.

Comment: you cannot convert a `list` to a `string` using `str`.

Comment: and this is why I shouldn't be doing this late at night... my apologies, answer has been updated to use join.